# How can I find "Exec" node's commands to program Raspberry Pi in Node-Red?

Tags: raspberry-pi, node-red

I am new at programming Raspberry Pi, can you help me to find commands for "Exec" node?

```
vcgencmd measure_temp
```

For example this code gives the temperature of Raspberry Pi if you write it on "Exec" node in Node-Red.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no list of commands for the exec node.

This node can be used to run **any** application that can be executed on the platform running Node-RED, in this case linux.

(These applications should be things that run without requesting any further input after starting and provided output to stdout/stderr)